# Outside object being changed within function

Tags: python, loops, matrix

So I am trying to make a determinant function for fun but I am coming across a problem within a specific part of my code.  It occurs during the creation sub matrix.  By this I mean, creating a new matrix by removing a column and row from the old one.
i.e.
going from:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

to a suba matrix say with col1 and row1 removed:

```
suba = [[5,6],[8,9]]
```

What I am trying to do is use a for loop to print out 3 sub matrices of the same original matrix, however each time the function runs it replaces the original matrix with the sub matrix.

my code is:

```
a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]


def submatrix(mat,row,col):
    '''
    Creates the smaller matrix by removing column and row of element.
    e.g. to remove the 1st column and row from matrix: M = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
    type: submatrix[M,1,1]
    '''
    temp = mat
    if len(mat) == 2:
        return mat
    elif len(mat) == 1:
        return mat
    else:
        for i in range(len(mat)):
            del temp[i][col-1]
        del temp[row-1]
        return temp


for e in range(len(a)):
    print submatrix(a,1,e+1)
```

What I want it to do is print out something like:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
[[4, 6], [7, 9]]
[[4, 5], [7, 8]]
```

but what is prints out is:

```
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
[[5, 6], [8, 9]]
```

and if I were to say, print a, it would now be this sub matrix.
how do I fix this?

Comment: @thefourtheye Actually, since it's a list of lists, he needs to make a deep copy... `temp = map(list, mat)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with `temp = mat`, `temp` points to the very same object as `mat`, so when you modify `temp` by deleting rows and columns, you are also modifying the original `mat` matrix, both inside and outside of the function.

To prevent this, you need to create a deep copy of your matrix, either using `copy.deepcopy`, or (specifically for copying lists of lists) by doing `temp = map(list, mat)`. This will make `temp` a *new* matrix (aka list of lists), holding *new* lists created from the rows in the original matrix.

Comment: So I am confused a little as to why I need to do this.
if I am assigning a one thing to another, ie if
a = 2
b=a
print b
2
a += 1
print a
3
print b
2

That was what I was expecting to happen.  I thought by saying temp = mat, now they both equal the same thing but they are not attached.  
Sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: When you do `a += 1` what you _really_ do is `a = a + 1`, i.e., you are not _modifying_ the value bound to both `a` and `b`, but assigning an entirely new value to `a`. But with `del temp[...]` you _modify_ the list, thus you need to make a proper copy, or you will modify it in each variable it is referred in.

Comment: Oh okay!  Thank you very much.  I this is my first attempt at modifying something rather than just replacing so it was not reacting as expected.  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Use `copy` module, import this in first line of your code:

```
import copy
```

And then in your `submatrix` function, change this line:

```
temp = mat
```

to

```
temp =  copy.deepcopy(mat)
```